# "One step behind" or "one move too late"

Tags: phrases

I heard this phrase that sounds like 「いいえ、**一手のさで**、私どもの勝ちです。」, which in the context should mean one is one step behind, or one move too late, or being overtaken by someone else in doing something. But I cannot catch what the last part (after の）means. I don't actually know for sure if the first two is 一手, but it looks to me the only possible fit. After の it might have been さて instead of さで, but I cannot search online with just this.

I am fairly sure this is not slang/colloquial, so I doubt it's a modification that does not appear in dictionary. What is the exact phrase, and if I heard wrongly what is the closest to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「一手{いって}の**さ**で、私どもの勝{か}ちです。」

It seems your listening comprehension is good.  You caught every single word at least.

It is just that the 「さ」 is 「差{さ}」 meaning "difference".

The word 「さて」 is not used here.

「一手の差で」, therefore, means "by the difference of a single move".

> "It is our victory by the difference of a single move."

No part of the sentence is indeed either colloquial or slangy.

Comment: Thanks! I was guessing 差 as a last resort and interpolate the meaning, so I am glad it is indeed the case. This has bugged me for a while :O